# How do I measure how well my data fits a prediction

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, terminology

Given a set of data like this:

```
x     y1            y2
50    102.50        16
100   408.60        64
200   1,871.30      256
400   8,824.40      1024
800   49,695.60     4096
```

My hypothesis is that when `x` doubles, you should find that `y` quadruples.

I believe this is equivalent to saying that `x` is proportional to the square of `y`.

---

We can see that the `y1` data (from my actual problem) are close to this hypothesis, but not in complete agreement; by comparison the `y2` data (which I have contrived) match my hypothesis exactly.

What I am looking for is some quantifiable measure of how much my data agrees with my hypothesis, and the correct terminology to discuss this type of test. I would expect that `y2` would be fully agree, and `y1` would provide some distance metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for "measure of model accuracy." One commonly used measure is [root mean squared error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation).  This is the loss functions that plain vanilla regression minimizes.  Another is [mean absolute deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_deviation#Mean_absolute_deviation).  A more complicated measure (for binary outcome models) is [AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_Under_Curve).  As you can imagine, there are many, many ways to skin this cat.

All of these measure compare `predicted` values to `actual` values, (or `expected` vs. `observed`.)  In your case, your model is y=(1/2)*x, so calculate a new variable pY, and compare it to the actual values for y.

Most statistics packages have all kinds of such functions built in.  It is advisable to measure them out-of-sample, either on a held-out test set, or through cross-validation.

Comment: Can you explain where your definition of my model as "y=(1/2)*x" comes from?

Comment: your hypothesis is `x*2=y*4`, correct?  By simple algebra, I get `y=(x*2)/4`, or `y=(1/2)*x`.  If that is incorrect, I'm sorry I misunderstood your hypothesis.  Perhaps you could clarify what you mean, in the form of a function y=f(x).

Comment: Ah, I see, yes it appears I was ambiguous in stating my hypothesis, I have edited the question and I hope it is clearer.

Comment: The hypothesis is that **y is proportional to the square of x** (not the other way around as stated).  In symbols, $y \propto x^2$.  The "simple algebra" is not correct for this formula, Zach.

Comment: @whuber: Dave revised his question.  Under the original formulation, I misunderstood his hypothesis to be x*2=y*4 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I have derived an answer to my own question, which is expressed upon the data I gave in my question, in [this Google docs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArXZTADO2Z54dE1DZ2VzZjFBbWUyRkFMYW82eFpYWVE).

I was inspired by Zach's answer, which suggested calculating a predicted value, and then using RMSE. I realised that by taking the square root of each of the `y` data I would I obtain a linear series. I can then do linear regression to get get a predicted value which can then be squared.

I suspect I might be doing something terrible here, insomuch as I'm not sure what my error value of `936.22` for `y2` actually corresponds to.